# Yii2: Format currency with thousands separator

Tags: yii2, separator, phpword

I use [**`PhpOffice\PhpWord`**](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) for my Yii2 and Microsoft word 2016.

value data type `decimal(15,2)` when i download microsoftwordfile.docx from my project field value decimal show `10000.00` but i need `10,000.00`
how to config/coding them to show `10,000.00`

here **`myController.php`**

```
public function actionWord($id)
    {
     Settings::setTempDir(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/temp/');
     $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/path/to/microsoftwordfile.docx');
     $model = Dataexample::findOne($id);
     $templateProcessor->setValue(
         [
            'amount',
         ],
         [
            $model->amount,
         ]);
         $templateProcessor->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/path/to/microsoftwordfile.docx'); 
        echo Html::a('download', Url::to(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/path/to/microsoftwordfile.docx'), ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']);
     }
```

[image: in microsoftwordfile.docx]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use [**`yii\i18n\Formatter`**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter) to format the currency and it provides you the

> `thousandSeparator` : The character displayed as the thousands
>   separator (also called grouping separator) character when formatting a
>   number.

Go to your `common\config\main.php` if you are using **`app-advanced`** or the `app/config/main.php` if **`app-basic`** nad add the following under `components` array.

```
'formatter' => [
     'thousandSeparator' => ',',
     'currencyCode' => 'USD',
],
```

Now you can format any given number like below

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(100.25);
//will output 
$100.25

Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(1000.25);
//will output
$1,000.25

Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(100000.25);
//will output 
$100,000.25
```

You should change your function like below

```
public function actionWord($id)
    {
     Settings::setTempDir(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/temp/');
     $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/path/to/microsoftwordfile.docx');
     $model = Dataexample::findOne($id);
     $templateProcessor->setValue(
         [
            'amount',
         ],
         [
            Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency($model->amount),
         ]);
         $templateProcessor->saveAs(Yii::getAlias('@webroot').'/path/to/microsoftwordfile.docx'); 
        echo Html::a('download', Url::to(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/path/to/microsoftwordfile.docx'), ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']);
     }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. your explain so clearly

but I use this

  `Yii::$app->formatter->asDecimal($model->amount, 2, [\NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0]),`

because I don't want to show symbol currency code.

Comment: yeah, you can use `asDecimal()` if you don't intend to show the currency symbol, happy to help @ChonjaroenChauynoo :)